# How prove this $\frac{1}{2\pi h}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-i(p-p')x}{h}}x^n\varphi{(p')}dxdp'$

Tags: integration

> show that this integral:
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi h}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\dfrac{-i(p-p')x}{h}}x^n\varphi{(p')}dxdp'=\left(ih\dfrac{\partial }{\partial p}\right)^n\varphi{(p)}$$

where $i^2=-1$

maybe this use integration by parts？ But I fell very hard,and I can't prove it.

I think  first we must  this
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\dfrac{-i(p-p')x}{h}}x^ndx=?$$
and follow it can  use

integration by parts?

But I consider sometimes can't have this resulut

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\phi(p)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(p')\delta(p'-p)dp'\\=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(p')e^{\displaystyle i(p'-p)x}dxdp'$$ The last step follows from the Fourier expansion of $\delta(\cdot)$. Now, put $x/h$ instead of $x$ in the inner integral to get $$\phi(p)=\frac{1}{2\pi h}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(p')e^{\displaystyle \frac{i(p'-p)x}{h}}dxdp'$$ Differentiate with respect to $p$ both sides $n$ times to get $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\right)^n\phi(p)=\left(\frac{-i}{h}\right)^n \frac{1}{2\pi h}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(p')x^ne^{\displaystyle \frac{i(p'-p)x}{h}}dxdp'$$

Comment: Hello,why is first step is true?

Comment: Sorry, the $1/{2\pi}$ factor should come in step 2 after the fourier expansion. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Oh,Thank you +1,But maybe this problem have other methods

Comment: Maybe there are, but the presence of the differentiation makes this method very handy to use.

Comment: why is $$\phi{(p)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi{(p')}\delta{(p'-p)}dp'$$? and what's is $\delta{(x)}?$,Thank you

Comment: $\delta(\cdot)$ is called the dirac delta function and the above property follows from the definition of the delta function. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).